# GetValue reflection on iterating through collections and get item.ToString()

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

Inside Class TestClass:

```
public HashSet<string> Test = new HashSet<string>();
public List<string> Test2 = new List<string>() {"item1"};
public String Test3 = "lol";
```

Getting all properties with reflection:

```
TestClass c = new TestClass();
var properties = c.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);
```

Now I want to iterate through the collection properties only:

```
var value = property.GetValue(c);
if (typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(property.PropertyType) && property.PropertyType != typeof(string))
{
    var valueString = string.Empty;
    foreach (var item in (IEnumerable)value)
    {
        valueString += item.ToString() + " | ";
    }
}
```

Works fine. Except when the collection is empty I get the collection fullname on item.ToString() instead of nothing / string.empty:

```
Output:
for the list I get a valueString with "item1" but for the HashSet I get a valueString of "TestClass.HashSet"
```

Any way to fix that?

Comment: why does it enter the `foreach` if value is empty ?

Comment: This code doesn't even compile, for a start you're trying to assign a `HashSet` to ` List`. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: messed up writing the code. Should be fine now!

Comment: This is still not a [mcve]. You can't do `.GetValue(class)` for example.

Comment: should be good now

Comment: It looks like your code is not comprehensive and you call `property.ToString()` somewhere to get the collection fullname. `item.ToString()` shouldn't be called since collection is empty.

Comment: You are right the problem must be somewhere else. Thanks!